# CASE - WHEN When joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

```
AppDetailFee table has AppID (PK), TypeID, Amount
AppDetail table has AppID (PK)
```

I join both tables on AppID and I need to check the following for TypeID and amount.   There are 3 scenarios:

```
If TypeID = 6 and Amount = 0 then  print appid and amount zero
If typeID = 6 and amount <> 0  - bypass and do not print
When TypeID <> 6 then print zero
```

Below is the code that I used, btu I get a result of all the rows that are not equal to zero with an amount of zero.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
SELECT  ad.AppID
      , MAX(case when (adf.TypeID = 6 AND adf.Amount = 0) then 0 
                 when (adf.TypeID = 6 AND adf.Amount <> 0) then Adf.Amount
       ELSE 0 END) AS FeeAmount

FROM         
      AppDetail AS ad   

inner join  AppDetailFee adf ON
      ad.AppID = adf.AppID 

WHERE  adf.Amount =0
```

Comment: just guessing here, but your where statement says "Where adf.Amount=0"  wouldn't that exclude any rows were adf.Amount <> 0.  meaning that the second case statement wouldn't ever be true.

Comment: This is definitely not the actual code you are using since you have an aggregate (`MAX`) without a `GROUP BY`, which won't even parse in SQL Server.  Show  your **ACTUAL** code please.

Comment: if you use MAX you also need to use GROUP BY clause

Comment: The group by was trancated when I copied my code into here.  I did say that the code was running but it had other issues.  therefore, the Group By is not missing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `WHERE` clause that is removing everything that does not meet the criteria:

```
WHERE  adf.Amount =0
```

Try removing that and running your query:

```
SELECT  ad.AppID
      , MAX(case when (adf.TypeID = 6 AND adf.Amount = 0) then 0 
                 when (adf.TypeID = 6 AND adf.Amount <> 0) then Adf.Amount
                 else 0 END) AS FeeAmount
FROM  AppDetail AS ad   
inner join  AppDetailFee adf ON
      ad.AppID = adf.AppID 
group by ad.AppID
```

You are also missing the `GROUP BY` clause on your query.

Comment: This is exactly it -- his other two `CASE` scenarios evaluate to 0, and he is only showing where the `Amount` is 0.

Comment: If I would miss the Group By - I would not get an answer, but I did get one, so I did have the group by clause.

Comment: All I need is to print when amount = 0 therefore I have the where clause = 0

Comment: @user1860212 The where clause is removing all rows that don't have an amount of zero, so you are not going to get anything that meets the second criteria of the case `adf.Amount <>0`.

Comment: based on the table structure, I added an extra table to join in and it worked